# How do you maintain style information of panels in wicket?

Tags: java, css, wicket

Been working with Wicket for a few weeks now and I'm stumped on the best way to maintain styles on panels in markup.  For example, pretend I have the following panel (ignore the Java side, I don't believe it is relevant):

```
<wicket:panel>
  <div class="brick"></div>
</wicket:panel>
```

Now I'm building a new component as follows:

```
<wicket:panel>
  <div class="wall">
    <div wicket:id="aBrick" class="good"></div>
    <div wicket:id="bBrick" class="bad"></div>
  </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

So, our wall has a good brick and a bad brick.  To give this some context, assume that classes good and bad do things for layout, like adding `float:left` for the good class and `float:right` for the bad class.  Ideally, the final markup would appear as follows:

```
<div class="wall">
  <div class="brick good"></div>
  <div class="brick bad"></div>
</div>
```

However, with the current code I seem to be limited to one of two options:

A) Output all the markup, with the final markup appearing as follows:

```
<div class="wall">
  <div class="good">
    <div class="brick"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bad">
    <div class="brick"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- OR -

B) Call setRenderBodyOnly(true) on the bricks, with the final markup appearing as follows:

```
<div class="wall">
  <div class="brick"></div>
  <div class="brick"></div>
</div>
```

In option A I now have an extra wrapper div that I didn't want which may or may not mess up my layout.  In option B I lost the class that was controlling my layout.  Both of these options are unacceptable in my mind, but I don't know the proper resolution for them.

It seems I could sub-class the brick panel so that I have a good brick and a bad brick panel, but the amount of code required for this solution is atrocious.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

> (ignore the Java side, I don't believe it is relevant)

Actually, it might in fact be easiest to do this cleanly on the Java side.

In your code for the "wall" component, you likely have something like:

```
add(new BrickPanel("abrick", ... );
add(new BrickPanel("bbrick", ... );
```

You can use `AttributeAppender` to add the varying classes in Java:

```
BrickPanel a = new BrickPanel("abrick", ... );
BrickPanel b = new BrickPanel("bbrick", ... );
a.add(new AttributeAppender("class", "good"));
b.add(new AttributeAppender("class", "bad"));
add(a);
add(b);
```

If they share a common "brick" class attribute, that can be left in the shared markup.  This appender will just add the "good" or "bad".

You could also subclass of course, and the amount of code to distinguish the two would amount to using different attribute appender calls in the two subclasses, so it's indeed not atrocious.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was hoping to avoid something like this for two reasons.  First, I really don't like having the classes applied in the Java because it ruins the preview-ability of the html.  I know I could apply the class in both places, but then I have duplicate code that could get out of sync.  Second, creating an entire Java class just to wrap a CSS class used specifically for layout (and it's the layout part that bothers me) seems verbose.  This may just be more of a problem that can't be handled well in html because usually the panel contents and layout manager are separate.

Answer (score 0):

With this markup:

```
<wicket:panel>
  <div class="wall">
    <div wicket:id="goodBrickPanel"></div> 
    <div wicket:id="badBrickPanel"></div>
  </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

Create z `BrickPanel` and set the classes there:

```
class BrickPanel extends Panel
{
    public BrickPanel(String id, boolean someCondition)
    {
        super(id);
        String cssClass = "brick " + someCondition ? "good" : "bad";
        add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", cssClass));
    }
}
```

PS. Avoid `setRenderBodyOnly(true)` where you can. You might in future need this tags either for styling or for ajax updates.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I understand this answer, but it frustrates me because doing things this way removes the preview-ability of the html.  This is also frustrating because it forces code outside my original panel (the "brick") to apply the brick class.  I want to be able to add the brick component to my page and it is always a brick without further effort.  I'm thinking this isn't possible with Wicket, but I would really like to find a better way if it is available.  However, this may be as good as it gets.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: When it comes down to preview-ability then there is no problem - you can still have the CSS classes "brick good" and "brick bad" in html. The `AttributeModifier` will *replace* them.

Comment: That is true, however it requires what amounts to code duplication.  If they ever get out of sync, it could cause unexpected behavior.  From a code perspective there doesn't appear to be any logical flow to accomplish what I want.  It seems what I really want is a way to separate the layout management from the styling.  Unfortunately, in html/css they are the same thing.  I think I have a work-around using a convention, but it is awful.  I might just make the layout stuff inline styles and everything else classes.  That way I can control classes in the panel and handle layout in html. *sigh*